# dotnet-run command not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to run my simple demo of .NET Core project in VS code. When I run `dotnet build` in my VS Code terminal, it works as expected. But the problem is, in the same project, when I run `dotnet run` then I get the following error:

> Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in C:\Users\hp\Desktop\HW-3\FirstTestApp, or pass the path to the project using --project.

This error is totally unexpected for me because this project should be working correctly, but it does not. I am actually not much familiar with VS Code.

[image: cmd.exe dotnet run fails]

Simplyfied `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` create this output

```
PS C:\FirstTestApp>dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   Restore completed in ... for \FirstTestApp\FirstTestApp\FirstTestApp.csproj
   FirstTestApp -> C:\ ...\FirstTestApp.dll
   FirstTestApp -> C:\ ...\FirstTestApp.Views.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

PS C:\FirstTestApp>dotnet build
Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in C:\FirstTestApp, or pass the 
path to the project using --project.
```

And this is my demo project structure:

[image]

Comment: Post any code and errors as text, not images. Images can't be copied, googled or compiled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dotnet build` will build using a solution file if one is present (the `*.sln` file).

`dotnet run` however *requires* a project file (`*.csproj`).

The easy fix is to just change into the project directory, and then run `dotnet run` again.

```
cd C:\Users\hp\Desktop\HW-3\FirstTestApp\FirstTestApp
dotnet run
```

The documentation for [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) and [dotnet run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) sort of makes this clear - the `dotnet build [<PROJECT>|<SOLUTION>]` command clearly can accept a project or solution file, whereas `dotnet run [--project <PATH>]` can only accept a project file.

If you are completely new to C# then I will just briefly explain that a .csproj project file is the file that tells the build toolchain how to build the project - it does the same job as a makefile, ant file, pom.xml file, or the main file from any other build system.

The solution file basically just links together several projects into a single solution such that opening the solution file in your editor (VS or VS Code) causes the projects to be loaded as well.